# Why do my href paths need an extra '/' when testing a webpage on AWS vs testing locally?

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services

I am learning the basics of web development as well as AWS. I am building a dummy webpage have the following workspace structure:

- styles/
- index.html

my stylesheet link looks like this:

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/styles.css">

My problem is that when I open the file locally, instead of navigating the webpage through the web, this href does not work for my stylesheet and I have to remove the first **'/'**:

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">

I am on a windows 10 machine, in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are few basics which has to be known while linking style sheets or any external style sheets.

Please see the below example. Assuming the below script is nested under the `assets/pages folder`. Inside `access.html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../theme/theme-blue.css">
```

**Explanation:**

1. .(dot) indicates current directory
2. ..(dot dot) indicates go two levels above from the current directory and then point to theme folder.
3. Then inside theme folder look for `theme-blue.css`

**Image Explanation:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the helpful explanation and image. My question was more about why "/styles/styles.csc" functions properly on AWS, but not when testing locally. the opposite is also true that "styles/styles.css" works locally but not on AWS. I wanted to find a path that works on both. 

I have since found the solution in "./styles/styles.css"

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution with help from Ragavan Rajan's answer:

> <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">

"**./**" being the difference.